# How to identify data points that are significantly smaller than the others in a data set?

Tags: statistics

I have an array of data points of real value. I wish to identify those data points whose values are significantly smaller than others. Are there any well-known algorithms?

For example, the data set can be {0.01, 0.32, 0.45, 0.68, 0.87, 0.95, 1.0}. I can manually tell that 0.01 is significantly smaller than the others. However, I would like to know are there any analysis method for this purpose in statistics area? I tried outlier detection in my data set, but it cannot find any outliers (such as detecting 0.01 as outlier).

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted a segment I wrote explaining the use of zscores for your problem but it was incorrect, I hope the information below is accurate, just in case, use it as a guide only...

The idea is to build a z-distribution from the scores you are testing, minus the test score, and then use that distribution to get a zscore of the test score. Any z greater than 1.96 is unlikely to belong to your test population.

I am not that this works properly because you remove your tests score' influence from the distribution, thus large scores will have inflated zscores because they contribute to a greater variance (the denominator in the zscore equation).

This could be a start till someone with a modicum of expertise sets us straight :)

e.g.

```
for i = 1:length(data_set)
    test_score = data_set(i)  
    sample_pop = data_set(data_set~=test_score)
    sample_mean  = mean(sample_pop)
    sample_stdev = std(sample_pop)
    test_z(i) = (i-sample_mean)/sample_stdev
end
```

This can be done for higher dimensions by using the dim input for mean.